# php & pdo & mysql countrows returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I have now spent several hours without getting anywhere. 
I want to display number of rows in my query and here here is my code:

```
 <?php 

        $user_id = 1;


        $statement = $dbConn->query("select badoo_interest.*, badoo_category.icon_class from badoo_interest, badoo_user_interest, badoo_category where badoo_user_interest.interest_id = badoo_interest.id and badoo_user_interest.user_id = :id_user_profile and badoo_category.id = badoo_interest.category_id");
        $statement->execute(array(':id_user_profile'=> $id_user_profile));


        $rResult = $statement->fetchAll();
        echo count($rResult);
        echo "<h2>Interesi</h2>";
        while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){

            ?>
                <div class="interest" id = "int<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                    <span class = "intr-ico <?php echo $row['icon_class'];?>"></span>
                    <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                </div>
            <?php
        }


    ?>
```

And i getting number 10 but now im not getting any interests displayed. 
If you use this code now:

```
<?php 

    //$user_id = 1;


        $statement = $dbConn->query("select badoo_interest.*, badoo_category.icon_class from badoo_interest, badoo_user_interest, badoo_category where badoo_user_interest.interest_id = badoo_interest.id and badoo_user_interest.user_id = :id_user_profile and badoo_category.id = badoo_interest.category_id");
        $statement->execute(array(':id_user_profile'=> $id_user_profile));
        echo "<p>"  . $statement->rowCount(). " interests:</p>";


        while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){

            ?>
                <div class="interest" id = "int<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                    <span class = "intr-ico <?php echo $row['icon_class'];?>"></span>
                    <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                </div>
            <?php
        }


    ?>
```

And now im getting all the interests displayed but it counts: 0 interests.
Any ideas who i can count number of interests?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for **[PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)** you will see this line

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. **However, this behaviour is not
>   guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.**

The work around is to `count()` function from php like you did. If that did not work then use  `COUNT(*) as result_count`. then when you fetch read that value.

---

> And i getting number 10 but now im not getting any interests displayed

**problem**

The reason why the result aren't displaying is because you fetched all the row already so you cannot use `fetch()` again.

**solution**

Use the array returned by `fetchAll()` instead and use a `foreach` instead

```
$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
echo "<p>"  . count($rows). " interests:</p>";

foreach ($rows as $row){
//echo $row['name']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    //$user_id = 1;


        $statement = $dbConn->query("select badoo_interest.*, badoo_category.icon_class from badoo_interest, badoo_user_interest, badoo_category where badoo_user_interest.interest_id = badoo_interest.id and badoo_user_interest.user_id = :id_user_profile and badoo_category.id = badoo_interest.category_id");
        $statement->execute(array(':id_user_profile'=> $id_user_profile));
        echo "<p>"  . $statement->rowCount(). " interests:</p>";
        $counter = 0; //declare counter

        while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
                 $counter++; //increment counter
            ?>
                <div class="interest" id = "int<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                    <span class = "intr-ico <?php echo $row['icon_class'];?>"></span>
                    <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                </div>
            <?php
        }


    ?>
```

[NOTE: Edit by @DinoAmino removed the emphasis characters around the two uses of `$counter`, which caused the code to not compile for the question asker]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like this:

**Here is the updated solving version.** Thank you all for the input:

```
<?php 

    $user_id = 1;

    $statement = $dbConn->query("select badoo_interest.*, badoo_category.icon_class from badoo_interest, badoo_user_interest, badoo_category where badoo_user_interest.interest_id = badoo_interest.id and badoo_user_interest.user_id = :id_user_profile and badoo_category.id = badoo_interest.category_id");
    $statement->execute(array(':id_user_profile'=> $id_user_profile));

    $rows = $statement->fetchAll();
    if(count($rows) >= '1') {

    ?>
        <div class="your-interests">
            <?php

            echo "<p>"  . count($rows). " interests:</p>";
            foreach ($rows as $row){

                ?>
                    <div class="interest" id = "int<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                        <span class = "intr-ico <?php echo $row['icon_class'];?>"></span>
                        <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                    </div>
                <?php
            }


            ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```